# removing 0 values in key value inside key value pair in json

Tags: c#, .net

I'm return json format returning like

```
var JsonObj = {
 "Date": "2016-12-15T08:55:53.77Z",
 "Location": "UK"
 "rates": {
   "ABC": 1.6403,
   "DEF": 1.6029,
   "GHI": 0
 }
}
```

how can i delete GHI from the json as i dont want zero values return in c#

Comment: Your JSON string is not valid.

Comment: I edited the question please anyone look into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have these two classes:

```
public class Rates
{
    public double ABC { get; set; }
    public double DEF { get; set; }
    public int GHI { get; set; }
    public bool ShouldSerializeGHI()
    {
        if (this.GHI == 0)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public Rates rates { get; set; }
}
```

you can serialize your object to a JSON string which ignores the rates with the value of zero:

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test);
```

Comment: Hi Mahdi,Thanks for the response, but in my code debugger its not hitting the bool shouldserialize method when it enters into rates class?

Comment: Thank you mahdi, its worked the code idea you gave .

Answer (score 0):

Before you convert the data to JSON you can remove the values which are zero and send the JSON.
Or you can have a check at the front end(Where this JSON data is being sent at) whether the key contains value zero.

Comment: Can you please let me share ,how do i filter out the values zero before returning json in my scenario?

Comment: Is the data a property from the class which you convert into JSON?

Comment: Check out Mahdi's answer i believe that is correct.